# PHPUnit doesn't see files from other directories

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit

I have this file structure for my project:

```
- Root
 -- /src
 -- /tests
```

I have placed my test on the `tests` directory.

When all included files are in the root folder everything works fine, but when I want to put my files in src I get the error:

> Warning: require(../src/Task1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\CodewarsPHP\tests\Task1Test.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../src/Task1.php'    (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in    E:\xampp\htdocs\CodewarsPHP\tests\Task1Test.php on 2 line

My test file:

```
<?php
require '../src/Task1.php';
class Task1Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTask1(){
      $this->assertEquals([1,1,1,3,5,9],fib([1,1,1],6));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling us how you call/run phpunit, but I'm guessing the phar file doesn't reside in the same folder than your testing script.

Then, when you do

```
require '../src/Task1.php';
```

On execution time PHP will resolve the location for Task1.php **relative to phpunit script**, instead of relative to **Task1Test.php**.

You can use `__DIR__`, which is resolved at runtime as the directory where the file the constant is used is, and then use an absolute path to `require` your file:

```
require __DIR__ . '../src/Task1.php';
```